# Same key has already been added then trying to name rows

Tags: c#, dictionary, rows

In my conversion program I am using a dictionary to gives names to specific rows read from a pre defined text file. Then creating a multidimensional array named "Rows" an error occurs:

> An item with the same key has already been added.

The following piece of code is written:

```
        Dictionary<string, int> rows = new Dictionary<string, int>();

        // The file "read.txt" is being read 
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("read.txt");

        int[] array = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

        // In this section each line is being read and the spacing is removed 

        foreach (string s in lines)
        {
            string[] arr = s.Split(' '); // This line ables the program to differ between variables and numbers. 

            for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
            {
                array[i] = Convert.ToInt32(arr[i]); // arr is now converted into a Int.

                rows.Add("array" + i, array[i]);

            }
        }
```

Then debugging the error occurs then the loop is ended. Why does the error appear and how do I fix it?

Comment: A clue: you are adding "rows" for each line readed. And each time, your index starts with 0...

Comment: Quote 'Then creating a multidimensional array named "Rows"... Dictionary is *not* a multi-dimensional array. It is a collection of key-value pairs with unique keys. It doesn't allow you to add the *same* key ('array0' in this case) twice.

Answer (score 3):

If you have multiple lines, you will start at `"array" + i` == `array0` again. That item has already been added to the dictionary, hence the exception.

You have to keep in mind to number the lines too, so maybe you should format it like `"array" + "line" + lineNumber + "row" + i` or so.

Comment: Then I use two counters, a (created as `int a = 0;` `a++`, within the foreach)  and i (from the loop) the same error still appears. The code reads: `rows.Add("array" + a + i, array[i]);`

Comment: `a + i` could end up with just an integer, so eventually it still becomes `array0` if `a` and `i` are `0`. Try to use my code.

Comment: Same error, the code states: ` rows.Add("array" + "line" + a + "row" + i, array[i]);`

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary allows only one occurrence of a key, the error means you are adding the same key twice.

your for loop inserts `"array" + i` as key. On the second run of the foreach loop, i is 0 again, so you are actually inserting the `"item0"` twice, and are getting an exception.

Answer (score 0):

This is fore the users looking for the full functional solution. 
By combining the other answers I got a functioning piece of code. It returns what it is suppose to do.

```
namespace test_read_txt
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // A string is created for the 14 first element 


        Dictionary<string, int[]> rows = new Dictionary<string, int[]>();


        // The file "read.txt" is being read 
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("read.txt");

        // In this section each line is being read and the spaceing is removed 
        int counter = 0;

        foreach (string s in lines)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine(s);
            string[] arr = s.Split(' '); // This line ables the program to differ between variables and numbers. 

            int[] array = new int[arr.Length];

            for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
            {
                array[i] = Convert.ToInt32(arr[i]); // arr is now converted into a Int.
            }


            string key = "array_" + counter++;
            rows.Add(key, array);
            //ShowArray(array);

        }

        foreach (string key in rows.Keys)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{key}: {String.Join(" ", rows[key])}");
        }


        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void ShowArray(int[] arr) {
        foreach (var item in arr) {
            Console.Write(item + "-");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

}

The read file is a text file that looks like this, which is located in bin -> Debug of the program folder:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

the Output is each row as an int[] with a name array_0...array12. Enjoy!!

Answer (score -1):

You probably want to associate *multiple* int's to the key in the dictionary.  A Dictionary won't do for this, but rather a

```
Dictionary<string, List<int>>  or   Dictionary<string, HashSet<int>>
```

If you are using ("array" + i) as key, an int would do it.

Initializing an array with many 0's is not very nice, rather use new int[n].

With these small changes, here is my updated version:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace StackOverflow
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dictionary<string, HashSet<int>> rows = new Dictionary<string, HashSet<int>>();

        // The file "read.txt" is being read 
        string[] lines = new string[] { "1", "2", "1 2"};  //File.ReadAllLines("read.txt");

        // In this section each line is being read and the spacing is removed 
        foreach (string s in lines)
        {
            string[] arr = s.Split(' '); // This line ables the program to differ between variables and numbers. 

            int[] array = new int[arr.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
            {
                array[i] = Convert.ToInt32(arr[i]); // arr is now converted into a Int.

                string key = "array" + i;
                if (!rows.ContainsKey(key)) rows.Add(key, new HashSet<int>());
                rows[key].Add(array[i]);
            }
        }

        foreach (string key in rows.Keys)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{key}: {String.Join(", ", rows[key])}");
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Many further improvements are possible.

Comment: Your code throws away items. Not sure if that is what OP wants.

Comment: That depends what we want to achieve, to have a unique list for each entry in the dictionary, or not.  If not, List can be used instead of HashSet.

Comment: @PatrickHofman 
The output is strange. All arrays are equal 0 expect array 1 and 2 which are given as `array1: 0 1` and `array2: 0 1`, The expected output would be all arrays to be `arrayX: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0` except 'array1: 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0'

Comment: You are reusing the same array for the duration of the loop. You are adding the one and only array multiple times. @Erik